# PHP Verificar dispositivo mobile

Tags: php

Eu preciso via PHP, de alguma função que me indique se o dispositivo do usuário é mobile ou não, ou, que pelo menos me diga a resolução do mesmo. Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Se deseja pegar a resolução da tela pense em usar JavaScript, eu pessoalmente não conheço nenhuma solução de PHP para isso. Mas se quer realmente detectar aparelhos mobiles deixei um solução abaixo.

Answer (score 6):

No site [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) conseguimos scripts capazes de detectar aplicativos mobiles, e em diferentes linguagens.

O código em PHP é esse:

```
<?php
 $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

 if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
   header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

O código acima simplesmente testa se o user agent é mobile e redireciona a  chamada http.

Answer (score 6):

Bem conforme os colegas já postagem em geral se compara o USER-AGENT ou seja o próprio navegador para determinar se é mobile ou não, o problema ao meu ver é que existe muitos modelos de aparelhos e navegadores então as vezes vários podem passar batido, então o ideial seria usar o USER-AGENT combinado com [espressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) para garantir, mas isso também é chato e demorado, então eu tenho usado a classe [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/), que para mim tem sido bastante útil por que ela diz se é Tablet ou Telefone e qual o modelo exato também.

```
<?php
// Inclui e inicia a classe
require_once("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Testa se é Tablet ou Telefone
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
 echo "Diz que é um Dispositivo Movel";
}

// Função que testa e diz a versão do aparelho
echo $detect->version("iPhone"); // 3.1 (float)
?>
```

Quanto a detectar a resolução você só vai conseguir usando JavaScript já que PHP só roda do lado do sevidor ou seja ele não tem acesso ao Hardware da máquina em sí.

Para isso você pode usar 2 tipos de funções básicas que combinadas viram 4, pois é sempre altura x largura que são elas:

- [`screen.width`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp): Pega a largura da tela da pessoa ou seja a resolução que a máquina está operando ***800***[x600] ou ***1024***[x768] ou ***1920***[x1080].
- [`screen.height`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_height.asp): Pega a altura da tela da pessoa ou seja a resolução que a maquina esta operando [800x]**600** ou *[1024x]**768*** ou *[1920x]**1080***.
- [`screen.availWidth`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availwidth.asp): Pega a largura da tela da pessoa porém ela desconta as parte não usadas por você, como a barra de endereço do navegador a barra de rolagem, barra de favoritos entre outras que o usuário possa ter, ou seja ela é a área realmente utilizável do navegador e em geral sempre será menor que a área do "screen.width".
- [`screen.availHeight`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp): Pega a altura da tela da pessoa porém ela desconta as parte não usadas como a barra de endereço do navegador a barra de rolagem, barra de favoritos entre outras ou seja ela é a área realmente utilizável do navegador e em geral sempre será menor que a área do "screen.height".

**Mas atenção**: tanto `screen.availWidth` como a `screen.availHeight` não funcionam tão bem quanto deveriam e às vezes elas trazem valores estranhos.

```
<script>
var lagura = screen.width, altura = screen.height;
alert(lagura + " x " + altura);

var laguraDisponivel = screen.availWidth, alturaDisponivel = screen.availHeight;
alert(laguraDisponivel + " x " + alturaDisponivel);
</script>
```

Vale lembrar que existe outras formas de se capturar o tamanho da tela ou do documento HTML ou dos elementos, assim como a psoição do aparelho deitado *(landscape)* ou e pé *(portrait)*, vou deixar esse link - [First, Understand Your Screen](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/) - caso queira conhecer essas outras formas.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$symbian =  strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Symbian");

if ($iphone || $ipad || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $symbian == true) {
    echo "Olá, eu sou mobile";
} else {
    echo "Olá, eu sou um computador";
}
?>
```

Comment: as 7 primeiras linhas pega vários sistemas, o if verifica qual é o mobile, por exemplo, se for android, ele vai considerar verdadeiro e vai mostrar a msg "Olá, eu sou mobile", e assim vai com os outros sistemas. e o else caso vc acesse pelo computador ele mostra a msg "Olá, eu sou um computador"

Answer (score 2):

O melhor que eu achei espero ter ajudado!

```
<?php
$mobile = FALSE;

$user_agents = array("iPhone","iPad","Android","webOS","BlackBerry","iPod","Symbian","IsGeneric");

foreach($user_agents as $user_agent){

    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $user_agent) !== FALSE) {
        $mobile = TRUE;

        $modelo = $user_agent;

        break;
    }
}

if ($mobile){

    echo "Acesso feito via ".strtolower($modelo);

}else{

    echo "Acesso feito via computador";
}
?>
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição para mostrar o código que você tinha colocado. Quando postar código em perguntas ou respostas, utilize o botão amostra de código (`{ }`) no editor.